# More conditions needed for determining the moment of inertia

Tags: astrophysics, computational-physics, moment-of-inertia, neutron-stars

I am solving the moment of inertia for a neutron star using equations:

$$\frac{dI}{dr}=\frac{8\pi}{3}\frac{(\epsilon + P)f(r)j(r)r^4}{(1 − 2M/r)}\tag 1$$

$$\frac{d}{dr}\bigg(r^4j(r)\frac{df}{dr}\bigg) + 4r^3\frac{dj}{dr}f(r) = 0\tag 2$$

where $f(r)\equiv1−ω(r)/\text{ohm}$, and $j(r)\equiv\text{exp}(-ν/2)\sqrt{(1−2M/r)}$, with the conditions:

$$\frac{df}{dr}=0\quad\text{at}\quad r=0\tag 3$$
$$f(r=R) = 1 − 2I(R)/R^3\tag 4$$

where $R =\text{radius of the star}$, $\text{ohm}=0.0361$.

The above coupled system neither have any direct condition on $I(r)$ nor it have any explicit form of $f(r)$. My program ask for more condition $b/c$ in the above system eq. $(2)$ of 2nd order needs 2 conditions and eq. $(1)$ of 1st order must have one condition. So we don't have any direct condition on $I(r)$.

**Is there any more condition for $I(r)$? Can we use $I(0)=0$ from $I=m(r^2)$?** I am not sure if $I=m(r^2)$ is valid for the star like neutron star or any reliable code that start using eq. $(3)$ (form center of star) and iterate till eq. $(4)$ is satisfied.
.

Comment: I recommend using mathjax interface, here is a quick tutorial http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: i am new at this site don't know how to use math jax. i read you link it is helpful but take time, kindly if you understand my equation then edit these at math jax. next time I will type my problem at math jax

Comment: I tried to do that, but I don't understand what $f$ and $j$ are... any source for these equations?

Comment: f and j means f(r) and j(r)